# Is the Suunto Ambit compatible with the Bontrager DuoTrap Digital Speed/Cadence Sensor?

Tags: bike-computer, compatibility

Bontrager DuoTrap is ANT+ compatible as well as the Suunto Ambit (with firmare 2.0 or greater).

Since it's not possible to find any proof of concept on the internet (specialized sites, forums, etc...) about the compatibility of these two devices, is it possible to know of some of you guys got this working?

Comment: Since both items are ANT+ radios, they are compatible, by definition. There is no need to physically pair them to know that.  This question states that they are ANT+ compatible, and then says it is not possible to know if they will work together without trying it. Either there is a profound lack of understanding of the concept of ANT+, or this question was poorly phrased.

Comment: zenbike I know that every ANT+ device should be compatible.In practice that may not be the case (plenty of gadgets should be compatible with standards but everybody knows that standards are implemented differently...). Therefore before spending 500$ for a watch it's nice to have someone that confirms it works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Definitely **YES**.

It works both with **speed** and **cadence**!
I paired the "**bike pod**" and got both the two measurement. At first I tried to pair also the "cadence pod" without success and I thought it wasn't working but then I took a ride and found out that the cadence was showing!

Answer (score 2):

The ANT Wireless guys run a certification program and post the certified devices on a directory, you can find the Duotrap on there.
http://www.thisisant.com/directory/duotrap-digital-speed-cadence-sensor/